# The best way to simulate macro in C#?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, macros, async-await

As C# doesn't support macros, I'm looking for another (hopefully, elegant) way to write a method which returns values of different types depending on conditional compilation symbols. E.g. (if macros were possible)

```
#if ASYNC
  #define ASYNC_VOID async Task
#else
  #define ASYNC_VOID void
#endif
```

...

```
ASYNC_VOID Connect()
{
  ...
}
ASYNC_VOID Disconnect()
{
  ...
}
ASYNC_VOID Post()
{
  ...
}
ASYNC_VOID Delete()
{
  ...
}
```

I'd better not create Connect and ConnectAsync methods separately as they don't need to co-exist in assembly at the same time and the code duplication will be excessive (thanks to async/await model, sync and async version are very close).

I'd rather leave a single method, just let it compile in sync and async pattern.

Is it possible or I always have to write this for every method?

```
#if ASYNC
  async Task
#else
  void
#endif
Connect()
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: I would heavily advise against doing that.

Comment: The async/non-async implementations are also going to be radically different, and not just have different return types.

Comment: 99.99% of the time you should have both versions in a library. Also c# is not C, compiling an assembly means producing metadata that includes method signatures...

Comment: Why?  You are trying to do something weird, which probably means you have got the wrong idea about something.

Comment: @Servy I know there will be differences in implementation too, they are still pretty easy for me to be both implemented in the same method.This part doesn't cause problems.

Comment: you could use t4 and code generation.

Comment: Changing the return type is not enough. You'd have to strip out all awaits and change methods that you call.

Comment: @JK. I have sync version of the library and I now need to provide its portable version. It won't have sync methods at all, only async. Both versions will coexist. The fact that there will be no sync methods in portable version is not a relax for me (like "it's better to have both sync and async but let's throw sync away if it makes things easier"). No, there must be no sync methods in async version (like when you don't have sync sockets in .NET for Windows Store apps).

Comment: @usr sure, that's why in my question I used #define ASYNC_VOID async Task, not just #define ASYNC_VOID Task

Comment: @Alex Changing the return type isn't going to remove all `await` calls and change all asynchronous methods to the synchronous counterparts (if they exist) or do the reverse.

Comment: Always assume that the developer who will be burdened by the  maintenance of your code is a dangerous maniac who might come after you. So don't do this.

Comment: @Servy he can just compile both versions into DLLs and use them separately... this is very "doable"... even if it's a bad idea...

Comment: @AK_ That does nothing to address the concern that I've brought up.  I'm saying that one problem, even if solved, won't successfully allow him to create two compilable DLLs.  It will have "corrected" the method signature, but not its implementation.

Comment: @Servy look at my answer. one could use processor directives to achieve what you are talking about...

Comment: @AK_ Look at my comments, the whole point is that I'm saying one would need to not just change the signature, as the OP is asking about, but have radically different implementations as well, and that transformation is going to be non-trivial.

Comment: @Servy yes. but as i did with the type of `thing` variable at the end of my example, one could do the same and have different implementations.

Comment: @AK_ I never said anything to the contrary.  All I said was that he would need to provide radically different implementations for all of these methods.  You're showing how he could provide completely different implementations; I'm simply saying he'll have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here. You have an example of C# [preprocessor directives](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed8yd1ha.aspx) below. You'll also probably need this [/define compiler directive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0feaad6z(v=vs.71).aspx) , but notice the #define at the beginning of the source.

you also have [conditional methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288458%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

**Now never use this.**

```
#define abc   
namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Class5
    {
        public
#if abc
 int
#else
    string
#endif
 Foo()
        {
#if abc
            return 7;
#else
    return "aa"
#endif
        }

        public void Bar()
        {
            #if abc
            int
#else
    string
#endif
 thing = Foo();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's the wierdest code i've ever seen. I can literally smell it.

Comment: The code indeed looks weird but I'm afraid the only alternative for me would be full duplication of sync code to async methods with minor corrections in async version (await, Async suffixes in framework method names and so on). 90-95% of the code would remain intact. I just have to choose lesser of two evils.